# How can I prevent bootstrap collapse from making overlapping divs when their size is variable during program usage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/silkpuma/fb1gqxh5/#&togetherjs=Pt1jA1Ri2K

When using bootstrap collapse my div sizes can change. This leads to my divs then overlapping. I tried using a container with row for each section of my program that I don't want to overlap but when my repair div gets larger due to bootstrap collapse it overlaps my next element. I tried changing positions but nothing would prevent then from overlapping when the size changes.

```
<body style="background-color: #e5e5e5">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #e5e5e5">

    <div class="row">
        <div style="height: 100vh; margin: 0 -15px 0 -15px; background-image: url('assets/bg.jpg');"   class="bg-image">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light " >
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: transparent !important;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">iRepair</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div style="background-color: transparent !important;" class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent" >
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#repair">Repair</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#purchase">Purchase</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#location">Location</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">(540)421-5581</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      <div style="background-color: transparent !important; padding-top: 24px" class="text-center position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" >
      <h1>iRepair</h1>
      <h5 style="margin-bottom: 24px">Harrisonburg's original professional Phone & PC Repair Shop.</h5>
      <a style="margin-right: 8px" class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="#repair">Repair</a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="#purchase">Purchase</a>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="repair" class="container" style=" padding-top: 24px; height: 50vh; text-align: center" >
    <h1>Device Repair</h1>
    <p></p>
    <h5 style="padding-bottom: 96px">All your electronics are welcome! We have the tool and expertize your device needs.</h5>
    <!--  device repair option-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center row img-fluid panel-group" >

      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6" style="align-items: center"  >
        <img class="img-fluid img-size card-img-top" src="assets/iphone/iphone13.png" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#iphoneRepair'" class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button"  data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#iphoneRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            iPhone Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6" style="align-items: center">
        <img class="img-fluid img-size card-img-top" src="assets/iPad/ipadPro2021.png" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#ipadRepair'" class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ipadRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            iPad Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6 text-center" >
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid img-size" src="assets/Android/s21.png"  alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#AndroidRepair'" class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#AndroidRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Android Phone Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6 text-center" >
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid img-size" src="assets/Android/galaxyTab.webp"  alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#AndroidTabletRepair'" class="btn   card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#AndroidTabletRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Android Tablet Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-size img-fluid " src="assets/Macbook/macbookTop.png"  alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#PcRepair'" class="nav-link btn   card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#PcRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Mac/PC Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-formatting card col-md-4 col-6 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid img-size" src="assets/watch/appleWatch.png"  alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button onclick="location.href='#WatchRepair'" class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#WatchRepair" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Smart Watch Repair
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <!--DevicesInterface show hide panels-->
  <div  style="height: 50vh" class="container-fluid" id="chooseDevice">


    <!--  iPhone Repair-->

    <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="iphoneRepair">
    <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select iPhone</h1>

  <!--    Iteration for device-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let iphone of iphones" >
       <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center" >
        <img src="{{iphone.deviceImg}}" class="img-product-details card-img-top" alt="...">
         <div class="card-body">
        <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button"  data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + iphone.repairId">
          {{iphone.deviceName}}
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>

  <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
       <div class="img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#iphoneRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{iphone.repairId}}">
        <h3 class="card-title " style="padding: 48px 0 48px 0;">{{iphone.deviceName}} Repair Cost: <p style="font-size: medium">Select the repair you are interested in to schedule an appointment!</p></h3>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div *ngFor="let repair of iphone.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-12 text-center">
            <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="card-img-repairs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
            <div class="card-body ">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
              <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>

              <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my {{iphone.deviceName}} {{repair.repairTitle}} repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

         <p></p>
         <p></p>
         <div class="justify-content-evenly">
           <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
           <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
           <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
         </div>
         <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">

      </div>

    </ng-container>

    </div>







      <!--  Ipad Repair-->
    <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="ipadRepair">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select iPad</h1>

        <!--    Iteration for device-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let ipad of ipads" >
          <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{ipad.deviceImg}}" class="annoying-imgs card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + ipad.repairId">
                {{ipad.deviceName}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
          <div class=" img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#ipadRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{ipad.repairId}}">
            <h3 class="card-title " style="padding-bottom: 48px; padding-top: 24px">{{ipad.deviceName}} Repair Cost: <p style="font-size: medium">Select repair</p></h3>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div *ngFor="let repair of ipad.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="card-img-repairs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
                  <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>
                  <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my {{ipad.deviceName}} {{repair.repairTitle}} repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="justify-content-evenly">
              <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
              <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
              <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>





    <!--


    ANDROID PHONE REPAIR


    -->
      <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="AndroidRepair">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select Phone</h1>

        <!--    Iteration for device-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let android of androidPhones" >
          <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{android.deviceImg}}" class="annoying-imgs card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + android.repairId">
                {{android.deviceName}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
          <div class=" img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#AndroidRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{android.repairId}}">
            <h3 class="card-title " style="padding-bottom: 48px; padding-top: 24px">{{android.deviceName}} Repair Cost: <p style="font-size: medium">Select repair</p></h3>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div *ngFor="let repair of android.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="card-img-repairs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
                  <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>
                  <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my {{android.deviceName}} {{repair.repairTitle}} repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="justify-content-evenly">
              <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
              <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
              <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>




  <!--

  ANDROID Tablet REPAIR

  -->
      <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="AndroidTabletRepair">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select Tablet</h1>

        <!--    Iteration for device-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let androidTablet of androidTablets" >
          <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{androidTablet.deviceImg}}" class="annoying-imgs card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + androidTablet.repairId">
                {{androidTablet.deviceName}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
          <div class=" img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#AndroidTabletRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{androidTablet.repairId}}">
            <h3 class="card-title " style="padding-bottom: 48px; padding-top: 24px">{{androidTablet.deviceName}}</h3>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div *ngFor="let repair of androidTablet.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="card-img-repairs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
                  <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>
                  <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my android tablet repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="justify-content-evenly">
              <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
              <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
              <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>




    <!--Mac/PC Repair-->
      <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="PcRepair">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select Computer</h1>

        <!--    Iteration for device-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let computer of computers" >
          <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{computer.deviceImg}}" class="annoying-imgs card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + computer.repairId">
                {{computer.deviceName}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
          <div class=" img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#PcRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{computer.repairId}}">
            <h3 class="card-title " style="padding-bottom: 48px; padding-top: 24px">{{computer.deviceName}}</h3>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div *ngFor="let repair of computer.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="card-img-repairs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
                  <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>
                  <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my computer repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="justify-content-evenly">
              <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
              <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
              <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>






    <!--Watch Repair-->
      <div class="px-lg-5 collapse justify-content-center row dropdown img-fluid" data-bs-parent="#chooseDevice" style=" padding-top: 48px" id="WatchRepair">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 96px">Select Watch</h1>

        <!--    Iteration for device-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let watch of watches" >
          <div class="card-formatting-devices card col-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{watch.deviceImg}}" class="img-product-details card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <button class="btn card-text stretched-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#' + watch.repairId">
                {{watch.deviceName}}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--      REPAIR DATA-->
          <div class=" img-fluid repair-info-div card-formatting-devices collapse justify-content-center" data-bs-parent="#WatchRepair" style="padding-bottom: 20vh" id="{{watch.repairId}}">
            <h3 class="card-title " style="padding-bottom: 48px; padding-top: 24px">{{watch.deviceName}} Repair Cost: <p style="font-size: medium">Select repair</p></h3>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div *ngFor="let repair of watch.repair"  class="card-formatting-repairs card col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
                <img src="{{repair.repairImg}}" class="annoying-imgs card-img-top img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{repair.repairTitle}} {{repair.repairPrice}}</h5>
                  <p>{{repair.repairDetails}}</p>
                  <a class="btn"><a class="nav-link active stretched-link" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581&body=Hi! I would like to get my {{watch.deviceName}} {{repair.repairTitle}} repaired. Can I schedule an appointment?"></a></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="justify-content-evenly">
              <h3 style="padding-bottom: 16px">Schedule your service!</h3>
              <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
              <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="background-color: black; margin-top: 24px">
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="text-center row " style="padding-top: 75vh">
        <div id="purchase"  >
        <h3>Devices for Sale</h3>
        <br>
        <p>Looking for a quality used phone? Look no further than iRepair! We sell new and quality used phones and iPads. Devices in stock are available for immediate pickup.</p>
        <p>Looking for something we don't have listed? We can order certain devices just for you!</p>
        <p>With unbeatable prices and service, choose us for your next Smart device!</p>
        <p>Call us today to see if we have the iPhone, iPad, Android, or computer you are searching for!</p>
      </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 160px" id="aboutUs">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p>We are a locally owned and operated iPhone repair shop that started back in 2014. We have qualified technicians that are
          happy to assist you and repair your device</p>
      </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 160px" id="contact">
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <p>Have a question? Need help? Get in touch with us by calling, stopping by</p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="justify-content-evenly">
          <button style="margin-right: 8px; font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="tel:+15404215581">Call</a></button>
          <button style=" font-size: large" class="btn btn-outline-dark"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="sms:+15404215581">Text</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="position-relative" style="margin-top: 160px" id="location">
      <h3>Location</h3>
      <div class=" mapouter" style="">
  <!--      position-absolute top-75 start-50-->
          <iframe width="100%" height="500px" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=924%20S%20High%20St,%20Harrisonburg,%20VA%2022801&t=&z=15&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
  <!--        <style>.mapouter{text-align:center;height:350px;width:350px;}</style>-->
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to simplify. We don't need to see four feet of code. Also, you can create your demo _here_ as a Stack Snippet using the editor.